# Передача файла через каналы/pipe

Tags: c++, c, pipes

Пишу клиент/серверное приложение, клиент вводит имя файла, сервер ищет етот файл у себя и передает его клиенту. Не могу найти никакого способа передачи файла от сервера к клиенту.

Comment: У Вас клиент и сервер на одном компе? В зависимости от этого можно использовать pipe (если на одном) или сокекты. Надо соответствующим образом ОТКРЫТЬ файловый дескриптор/сокет. А сама по себе передача не зависит от этого и может быть записана инвариантно, с помощь. операторов read/write в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали интересующую Вас ОС, поэтому вкратце опишу ситуацию для unix.
Вряд ли для Вашей задачи подойдут *pipe*, так как неименованные каналы обычно используются для связи родительского и дочернего процесса:

- родительский процесс создает неименованный канал и порождает дочерний
  процесс;
- один из процессов закрывает у себя, например, дескриптор на чтение,
  второй - закрывает дескриптор на запись, - получается соединение в
  одну сторону: родитель пишет данные, потомок читает, или наоборот.

Если ваш клиент и сервер выполняются на одной и той же машине, то для передачи файла можно посмотреть в сторону именованных каналов *fifo*. Они похожи на *pipe*, но, в отличие от них, имеют имя в файловой системе, и потому могут использоваться процессами, не связанными "родственными узами". Создаются именованные каналы с помощью функций *mkfifo()* или *mknod()*.

Если же Ваши клиент и сервер запущены на разных машинах, и Вам требуется передавать данные через сеть, то Вам придется познакомиться с механизмом сетевых сокетов *socket()*.